# One-way ANOVA analysis by row

Tags: r, loops, anova

I would like to do an ANOVA analysis to compare the differences between the 4 groups (ABCD). Each group contains an uneven number of replicates in different columns, and each row represents one individual item I would like to test. Each column you can treat as a replicate and there is no relationship between different rows. Eventually, I hope to figure out what item(row) showed significant differences between the 4 groups.

Please see below example data structure. In reality, all data are normalized already.

|  | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | C1 | C2 | D1 | D2 | D3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| protein1 | 15 | 30 | 28 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 30 | 45 | 66 | 43 |
| protein2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 56 | 54 | 23 | 25 | 12 | 13 | 5 |
| protein3 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 56 | 54 | 23 | 25 | 12 | 13 | 5 |
| protein4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 56 | 54 | 23 | 25 | 12 | 13 | 5 |

Comment: The standard way of doing this would be to have each observation as a row and each variable as a column. What is your opposition to reformatting the data?

Comment: I am not aginst reformatting this data, just don't know how to deal with this problem in a "standard way" in R.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

First reshape the data into a format that the model can handle. This uses the tidyverse package.

```
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:ncol(.)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = prot, values_from = value) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("trt"), sep = "\\d")
```

Which looks like:

```
   trt   protein1 protein2 protein3 protein4
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A           15        2        2        2
 2 A           30        4        4        4
 3 A           28        3        3        3
 4 B            6       56       56       56
 5 B            7       54       54       54
 6 C            9       23       23       23
 7 C           30       25       25       25
 8 D           45       12       12       12
 9 D           66       13       13       13
10 D           43        5        5        5
```

Then you can easily use whatever model/statistical test you would like to apply. For example, to generate an ANOVA for each column, you could define a helper function and then map over the columns:

```
fit_aov <- function(col) {
  aov(col ~ trt, data = df_long)
}

anovas <- map(df_long[, 2:ncol(df_long)], fit_aov)

summary(anovas$protein2)

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
trt          3   3648  1216.0   165.8 3.69e-06 ***
Residuals    6     44     7.3                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me!

Comment: @wanying1107 does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, it works really well. The only last step I cannot figure out is to print the p value of each protein in to a row. I use 
 summary(anovas$protein2)[[1]][1,5] to print the value of one protein but cannot figure out how to print them together into a row. Could you please kindly show me how as well? Thank you so much!